# "Be the first" in my sentence

Tags: word-choice

Is the definite article optional before "first"?

"If you want to have a highly-paid job you have to learn more and be the first."

Comment: First, what are you trying to say?

Comment: I mean "be the best."

Comment: Your sentence would be much clearer if you said "be the first **at ____**" or something.  Just "be (the) first." leaves it unclear what you mean, so it is hard to answer the question.

Comment: "Be first at work", for example. But "the" is optional in both, isn't it?

Comment: If I heard "be (the) first at work", I'd think you meant arrive earliest in the morning :) I think "be the best" is more idiomatic than "be the first" for the way you're using it.

Comment: Oh, then it simply doesn't work in my context. I will use "be the best". Is "the" optional?

Comment: You could "be the first in your class" though still with the slight potential they thought you wanted to be there earliest. "Best" is far less ambiguous. "The" is not optional in the construction you have there.

Comment: With "the best" it's not optional, but before "first" is it?